# Removing tr if td contains a text not working only in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, html-table

```
var searchString = 'teststring';
$("td").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == searchString) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="15%">teststring</td>
        <td align="center" width="15%">B</td>
        <td align="center" width="15%">C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The above script I am using it to remove the `tr` if any td have the match text. For some reason it is not working in *IE* (all version) and working fine in all other browsers.

Anyone know the reason for it ?

Comment: not an answer, but a suggestion to stop using IE or making exceptions for IE. Put a note as a developer, saying, you don't support IE since it doesn't follow web standards.

Comment: Can you share the html sample as well.. also which IE version....

Comment: Could be that there is leading/trailing spaces... so try `$.trim($(this).text()) == searchString`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fk6zebyb/1/ - working fine

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thankyou Arun, I'll try with that trim.

Comment: teststring != texttring - I assume that's a typo HERE on your part

Comment: Yes, fixed it ...thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which ie browser you are using.Anyway this snippet will help you.Tested in ie10

```
var searchString = 'teststring';
$("td").each(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == searchString) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
});
```

Used setTimeout in [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vpzovbhh/2/) just for demo